# How to make input tag take full width as it's parent with Styled Components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have an input field, whose width is set to a certain size. I want to increase its width to `100%` by selecting it from its parent component. Is it possible to increase the width without passing an explicit width prop in the `styled component`?
I tried replicating the same behaviour with [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-solomon-tz3t8?file=/src/App.js) sandbox. Here I am giving the width of the input box to be `100px` and I want to change the width from its parent component. I have tried changing it by selecting the input box like below, but it's not working-

```
  & > input {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
```

Comment: I think you cannot edit child elements from parent component without passing a prop that is changed in the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to apply style on input element under `WrapperOne` so if you want to control the grandchild from `WrapperTwo`, you either need to select the element one level down or without selector.

**01 Way: select child div - `WrapperOne` and select `WrapperOne` child - input**

```
const WrapperTwo = styled.div`
  & > div > input {
    width: inherit;
  }
`;
```

**02 Way: without selector, apply css to all inputs under it**

```
const WrapperTwo = styled.div`
  & input {
    width: inherit;
  }
`;
```

Here is the [codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-haze-h8if7?file=/src/App.style.js:41-524)

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @Mic